# Nesting templates that deploy different subnets in the same vnet with AzureRM

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-network, azure-rm-template

I am trying to achieve a level of containerization through templates. In the end, I would like to be able to define a component (one or more servers) that resides inside a virtual network and subnet (like a db cluster) in one template. Through another template, define a component that resides inside a virtual network and subnet, but possibly a different one.

Template A:

- my-vnet

  - my-subnet1

    - my-interface1

Template B:

- my-vnet

  - my-subnet2

    - my-interface2

Such that, nesting Template B inside Template A would leave me with:

Template AB:

- my-vnet

  - my-subnet1

    - my-interface1
  - my-subnet2

    - my-interface2

Instead I get the following error:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 4:56:27 PM - Resource 
 Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks 'overlayTest-vnet' failed with message '
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InUseSubnetCannotBeDeleted",
    "message": "Subnet overlayTest-subnet2 is in use by  /subscriptions/beep-boop/resourceGroups/d/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/overlayTest-vnet-interface2/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1 and cannot be deleted.",
    "details": []
  }
}
```

The resulting Resource Group is populated like this (as if the nested template deployed and the resources following the nesting quit).

Template AB:

- my-vnet

  - my-subnet2

    - my-interface2

And my template is as follows:

azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "solutionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "testing"
    },
    "vmIP": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.100.100"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'), '-vnet')]"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'),'-subnet1')]"
    },
    "subnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.100.0/24"
    },
    "subnetName2": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'),'-subnet2')]"
    },
    "subnetAddressPrefix2": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.101.0/24"
    },
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "OverlaySubnetTemplateFolder": "nestedtemplates",
    "OverlaySubnetTemplateFileName": "OverlaySubnet.json",
    "OverlaySubnetTemplateParametersFileName": "OverlaySubnet.parameters.json",
    "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "OverlaySubnet",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('OverlaySubnetTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('OverlaySubnetTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "solutionName": {
            "value": "[parameters('solutionName')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ],
        "virtualNetworkPeerings": []
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]",
        "privateAccessServices": []
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '/', parameters('subnetName2'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix2')]",
        "privateAccessServices": []
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '-interface1')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              /*
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
              // reserved IP address range for /24 is 1-3, so start with [0 + 4] or more
              "privateIPAddress": "[parameters('vmIP')]",
              */
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

nestedtemplates/OverlaySubnet.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "solutionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "testing"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'), '-vnet')]"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'),'-subnet2')]"
    },
    "subnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.101.0/24"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ],
        "virtualNetworkPeerings": []
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '-interface2')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              /*
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
              // reserved IP address range for /24 is 1-3, so start with [0 + 4] or more
              "privateIPAddress": "[parameters('vmIP')]",
              */
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was able to achieve my goal of creating a nested template that defines its own subnet within the virtual network of the parent template while maintaining the ability to deploy the nested template without it's parent. The key was to use a conditional virtual network resource and ensure the nested template does not clobber the parent template's virtual network when nested. Thanks to @4c74356b41 for pushing me in the right direction.

azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "solutionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "testing"
    },
    "vmIP": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.100.100"
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'), '-vnet')]"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'),'-subnet1')]"
    },
    "subnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.100.0/24"
    },
    "subnetName2": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'),'-subnet2')]"
    },
    "subnetAddressPrefix2": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.101.0/24"
    },
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "OverlaySubnetTemplateFolder": "nestedtemplates",
    "OverlaySubnetTemplateFileName": "OverlaySubnet.json",
    "OverlaySubnetTemplateParametersFileName": "OverlaySubnet.parameters.json",
    "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "OverlaySubnet",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('OverlaySubnetTemplateFolder'), '/', variables('OverlaySubnetTemplateFileName'), parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "solutionName": {
            "value": "[parameters('solutionName')]"
          },
          "createVirtualNetwork": {
            "value": "no"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ],
        "virtualNetworkPeerings": []
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]",
        "privateAccessServices": []
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '-interface1')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              /*
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
              // reserved IP address range for /24 is 1-3, so start with [0 + 4] or more
              "privateIPAddress": "[parameters('vmIP')]",
              */
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

nestedtemplates/OverlaySubnet.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "solutionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "testing"
    },
    "createVirtualNetwork": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "yes",
      "allowedValues": [
        "yes",
        "no"
      ]
    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'), '-vnet')]"
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16"
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat(parameters('solutionName'),'-subnet2')]"
    },
    "subnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "10.0.101.0/24"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "createVirtualNetwork": "[equals(parameters('createVirtualNetwork'), 'yes')]",
    "vnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks',parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetID'),'/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[variables('createVirtualNetwork')]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
          "addressPrefixes": [
            "[parameters('vnetAddressPrefix')]"
          ]
        },
        "subnets": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
              "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]"
            }
          }
        ],
        "virtualNetworkPeerings": []
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '/', parameters('subnetName'))]",
      "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
      "properties": {
        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('subnetAddressPrefix')]",
        "privateAccessServices": []
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '-interface2')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
        "[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              /*
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
              // reserved IP address range for /24 is 1-3, so start with [0 + 4] or more
              "privateIPAddress": "[parameters('vmIP')]",
              */
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change VNet resource to subnet resource in nested template and it will work. What you are trying to do it create a new vnet instead of existing one, so it tries to update existing one to match your definition (so remove all the subnets and add the 1 defined in overlay).

But honestly, whole approach is wrong, you should use properties copy loop and do everything in one go.